# Why is my bootstrap margin not returning a result?

Tags: bootstrap-4, margin

I have a big problem for several days.
The bootstrap margin dont work.

I have try "mr-md-4", "mr-4".
It's the same problem.

Is there something that I did not understand?
If so, I would love to learn it :)

Below is a demonstration JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gyfuLome/

My code :

```
<div class="row">
    <span style="background-color : blue;" class="mr-md-5 col-md-1">test</span>
    <span style="background-color : red;" class="col-md-1">test</span>
</div>
```

Thank you very much,
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSFiddle example `bootstrap.css` is missing, this is why the bootstrap classes like `mr-md-5` are ignored. Add the following URL to `Resources`:

`https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css`

It should look like this:

[image]

After adding the css url of bootstrap the classes of it work as expected:
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you very much !!!
In my project, I have import just the bootstrap.min.css file. 

I will learn more about bootstrap files.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer, if it resolved the issue. :)